# Manga/manhua where MC became a god of a game world

Tags: story-identification, manga

This sort of shut in gamer received a game from an unknown package. He later started the game and found out he saw like a god figure to the people. He can only give one prophecy to the people inside the game per day and can perform miracles by spending some kind of points. He gains more points by receiving sacrifices and trust from the people.

Oh, and the sacrifices he recieves from the in-game people also gets delivered to his house.

Comment: I only know chinese novel similar to the story. The MC call himself "The world observer". He give people a tape of what is happening if he don't interfer. He get 1% of what he changes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for the novel *NPC Town-building Game* that was adapted into the manga *This Village Sim NPC Could Only Be Human*

[image: Manga cover]

> An unknown parcel arrives to Yoshio, a 30-years old NEET. The content is a game disk titled “The Village of Fate” A beautiful CG game with real-life images gets started.
>
> All of the villagers in the game are high-performing AIs, who strangely behaved like human beings. In that game, Yoshio is the god of destiny and will be in a position to guide the villagers. But what can be done in the game is only to give a message, a prophecy, once every day. The villagers will execute the instruction, and their gratitude becomes the power of miracles, that the god of destiny can use.
>
> Yoshio is worshiped as God but in reality, he lives like a shut-in. Thanks to the villagers he will again learn the joy of life and thanks to him the villagers will be saved.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much!